# input does not autofocus when doing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm validating an input #rut_usu. I am looking for, if the value entered already exists in the database, if it exists, I show a message, this is done correctly once it is out of focus, the idea is that in doing so the other elements of the form are blocked, and it is autofocused again #rut_usu I have managed to self-only, if, when it is out of focus, when clicking out of the form, it does not, if it does in another input, that is the problem.

Javascript

```
$("#rut_usu").focusout(function(){
var parametros = {"rut_usu" : $("#rut_usu").val()};
//search
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>C_Usuarios/consultar_rut',
    data: parametros,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
    },success: function(data){                                                          
      if(data){ 
             window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.focus(); 
             window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.select();
            $('#btn_insert').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#resultado').html('<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">that RUT already exists in the Database</span>');
        }  
        else{  $("#resultado").addClass("hide"); return true;

        }
       }
      });
    });

   $("#name_user").keypress(function(){

   $("#name_user").removeClass("blanco");
   $("#msg_nom").addClass("hide");
  });
  $("#name_user").focusout(function(){         
  if($("#name_user").val().length<1){
     $("#name_user").addClass("blanco");
     $("#msg_nom").removeClass("hide");
        window.document.r_usuarios.name_user.focus();   
        window.document.r_usuarios.name_user.select();    
        return false; 
       }
       return true;
     })
```

With these lines, I have the field autofocus according to if, and the form is blocked. But in the case of #rut_usu, if I add the true or false, the function is not executed.name_user is another input with a similar validation, but if its value is blank, it works correctly. If anyone knows any other way to do it, I would still like it, thank you.

```
window.document.name_form.name_input.focus();   
window.document.name_form.name_input.select();    
return false;
```

Comment: cant you use a jQuery selector and then set focus? like `$('input[name=nombre_usu').focus();`

Comment: No, I understand what you mean, could you put a more explicit example and explain it? by the way name_usu is name_user, I need to change it well, so that it is understood, since it is another language.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#name_user").focus()` instead of

```
    window.document.r_usuarios.name_user.focus();   
    window.document.r_usuarios.name_user.select();
```

Comment: It works, just as it did for my code, but if I turn it down when I click on another input, the autofocus of that other input is executed, not the one of #rut_usu

Comment: In that case you should make the jQuery selector more variable.